# Display Little Endian Value from Selected Bytes?

Tags: c#, wpf, binary

I have a TextBox where I can select text. I would like to show the Little Endian value off to the right of what I highlight but am getting an error about the Input string was not in a correct format.

This code will put the bytes in one textbox, but as I tried to get the Int32 value out of it it breaks. If I hard code the value in where `BytesToConvert` is, such as `0x686F61`, then it would work.

```
private void TextSelected_Event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(DisplayArea.SelectedText);
    var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    if(ba.Length > 2)
    {
        string BytesToConvert = "0x";
        BytesToConvert += hexString.Replace("-", "");
        int IntConverted = Convert.ToInt32(BytesToConvert);
        int32LE.Text = Convert.ToInt32(IntConverted).ToString();
    }
    selectedHex.Text = hexString;
}
```

I tried doing a Int.Parse like this to turn the string to integer, but that didn't work either:

```
int IntConverted = Convert.ToInt32(int.Parse(BytesToConvert));
```

Comment: `am getting an error about the Input string was not in a correct format.` What line of code gave that error?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (preferably a complete code sample, with inputs included, that we could copy and paste into a console app and run). Be sure to specify the output that you expect for a given input.

Comment: What is this silliness with going from `byte[]` -> hex string -> `int`? You can go directly from `byte[]` -> `int`. BitConverter has specifically method(s) for this. (Not to mention that `ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(DisplayArea.SelectedText);` looks weird here. What is the point of this?)

Comment: I know it seems silly, just reverse engineering a 20 year old database and building some debugging tools. I found the issue was that I needed to use `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` in my int.Parse() function

Comment: PS, I didn't mean to be difficult, the only code not included in this was the WPF form, I am not sure how to provide a minimal example when including WPF view components.

Comment: If you have solved the issue you should add it as an Answer below @Alan.